# read data timeout in typo3 sites with many images

Tags: php, typo3, graphicsmagick

Pages with to many images on a typo3 site need to much time for imageprocessing to scale the images with graphicsmagic. The user gets the error: `500 Internal Server error.`

The error_log says this:

> mod_fcgid: read data timeout in 45 seconds

If I reload the page multiple times after a while all images are generated and cahed an it works.

My questions are:

1. can I force typo3 to generate all images without reload the page
2. can't typo3 show a better errorpage
3. are there any ohter solutions to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message already tells you the reason: TYPO3 needs more time, but your web server hits the timeout of 45 seconds and stops waiting for the PHP process.

Thus, it's not TYPO3 that creates the error page, but your web server software (Apache? nginx?)

Increase the timeout, it should be influenced by [FcgidIOTimeout](http://httpd.apache.org/mod_fcgid/mod/mod_fcgid.html#fcgidiotimeout) when using Apache.

Comment: Well, the problem is clear, but I think its not a goot solution to increase the timeout to the 5 minutes or more typo3 need...

Comment: Well.. then you (or your editors) have to open the page once, before other users can access it, in order to render the images. It also sounds you upload images with very high resolution? Smaller images reduce processing time.

Comment: .. what solution do you expect, when you hit a timeout? Reduce the processing time (smaller images, faster server, faster software) or increase the timeout.

Comment: Thats what I do today, but I'm searching for a better / automatic solution ;)

Comment: Depends on how often you hit such case, where pages with lots of images are generated. If images are added through a plugin (image gallery or so) you could create a scheduler job that pre-renders all images and afterwards makes the images publicly available.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds stupid, but the real problem was the performance of the server. I ordered a new / better one and solved the problem in most cases.